# Python throws a List Index Out Of Range Error

Tags: python, list, for-loop, list-comprehension

I tried list-comprehension, but aparrently I failed. Can someone please help?

I'm using python 3.7 on Windows 10 and I'm confused about why my code isn't working

```
import random
import lists  # includes the lists in the __init__ method

class PassGen:
    def __init__(self):
        password = []

        self.vowel_list = lists.vowel_list
        self.consonant_list = lists.consonant_list
        self.number_list = lists.number_list
        self.symbol_list = lists.symbol_list
        #self.characters = characters
        chars = str(input("How many characters do you want?\n"))
        for i in range(int(chars)):
            for i in range(len(chars)):
                password += self.vowel_list[random.randint(0, len(self.vowel_list))]
                password += self.consonant_list[random.randint(0, len(self.consonant_list))]
                password += self.symbol_list[random.randint(0, len(self.symbol_list))]
                password += self.number_list[random.randint(0, len(self.number_list))]

        print(len(chars))
        end_pass = ""
        for i in password:
            end_pass += i
        print(str(end_pass))

def main():
    #characters = str(input("How many characters do you want your password to be?\n"))
    passWord = PassGen()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Please provide the full traceback.

Comment: Note that `randint` can return numbers equal to the upper range. The upper bound isn't exclusive.

Comment: I was trying to create a very simple password generator app, still don't get why list index out of range error is there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`randint`'s upper bound is inclusive, as noted [in the docs](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/random.html#random.randint). That means that `randint(1, 3)` will randomly return the numbers 1, 2, and 3.

```
random.randint(0, len(self.vowel_list))
```

will randomly return numbers from 0 to `len(self.vowel_list)`; inclusive. The problem with that though is `len(self.vowel_list)` is out of bounds for the list `vowel_list`. If that list has 3 elements, there is no index 3 in that list. The highest index is 2 (since indices start at 0).

You need to subtract one from the upper bound to ensure that the indices stay in bounds:

```
password += self.vowel_list[random.randint(0, len(self.vowel_list) - 1)]
```

Or use the [`randrange`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/random.html#random.randrange) variant:

```
password += self.vowel_list[random.randrange(0, len(self.vowel_list))]
```